# How to set 'requiresuniqueemail' to false for identity?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, asp.net-identity, asp.net-membership

I have a web application and I am using the default membership system that an ASP.NET web forms project comes with in Visual Studio 2015. However I need a user to be able to create and login with an account with just a username and password and no email.

As far as I can tell however an email is compulsory when creating an account.
But it seems that it is possible to set a variable 'requiresuniqueemail' to false.

So my idea was to have one email for all users such as 'default@default.com'. How and where can I set this variable?

Answer (score -1):

I ended up finding a workaround. When registering an account I just add the username that was entered into the user name text box to the the front of an email string.

```
email = userNameTB.text + "@default.com"
```

Comment: The problem here is that default.com is an actual, valid email address. You don't want to be sending password resets and what not to who knows where (the default.com is currently a parking site, but anyone might have access to it).

Comment: Just saw this after many months. This wasn't an issue as the app was never going to be online or connected to the internet, just intended to be used on a local network. I suppose I should have mentioned that in the question